# How to detect modifier keys in delphi?

Tags: delphi

How can I detect that two or three combination keys are pressed?

For example when i press 'Shift + Ctrl + F1' how can i detect it in 'onKeyDown' event of a textbox?

Comment: `if (Shift = [ssCtrl]) and (Key = VK_F1) then DoSomething;`

Comment: tnx alot, but for pressing 'Shift+Alt+F1' what can i do? i mean how my app could understand that shift and alt are pressed in onKeyDown or onKeyUp?

Answer (score 5):

The `Shift` parameter to `OnKeyDown` is a set. It describes the state of all the modifier keys. Test for multiple modifier keys like this:

```
if (Shift*[ssShift,ssAlt,ssCtrl]) = [ssShift,ssCtrl] then
  ....
```

The `*` picks out the state of the three modifier keys from `Shift`. The test then checks for shift and ctrl being down, but alt not being down.

Such key presses are usually best handled by actions using the `ShortCut` property of an action.

Comment: tnx alot, best regards.

Comment: .. or `Shift = [ssShift, ssCtrl]`, depending on requirement.

Comment: @sertac I think you have to mask out the non modifiers